# 404 request not found (routing not working) when navigating in Laravel website after deploment

Tags: laravel, routes

I just finished deploying my Laravel project on a host, I uploaded the public folder files in `public_html` and beside the files I uploaded the whole project folder `fodler_name`,
so when you enter `public_html` you can find the public files beside the `folder_name` folder
and I edited the `index.php`

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

to this

```
require __DIR__.'/aqaraty/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/aqaraty/bootstrap/app.php';
```

and I edited the `.env` APP_URL and the ports and everything
but the routing doesn't working for no reason, the home page works fine but when navigate to any link it shays 404 request not found, please help

Comment: Did you tried ```php artisan route:cache``` ?

Comment: I already deployed the app, where can i type this?

Comment: you could run it on server, in the root directory for the web app

Answer (score 0):

This happends because you are setting to the wrong routes.

Your project structure is:

```
root
 | aqaraty
 | public_html
   | index.php
```

Change this:

```
require __DIR__.'/aqaraty/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/aqaraty/bootstrap/app.php';
```

To this:

```
require __DIR__.'/../aqaraty/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../aqaraty/bootstrap/app.php';
```